# Casting of generic T to List<T>

Tags: java, list, generics

I'm a bit confused with code below. The problem is that a code looks about List < T > has same type as T.
Considering method **makeList** receiving parameter of type DTOInt< T> and returns List< T>(list of T).
The class DTO implementing 'T getData() method' of DTOInt< T>, so we have DTOInt interface have generic definition T which is return type of getData() method.

So, inside of **makeList** method I do obvious casting of method **getData()** returned object(which is T type)   into List < T>.
And it compiling and running fine.

About compilation its clear - there is an obvious casting, but when it running how it not fails with   ClassCastException on casting line in makeList() method?

```
interface DTOInt<T>{
    T getData(); 
}

class DTO implements DTOInt<List<List<String[]>>>{
    public List<List<String[]>> getData() {
        String[] arr = {"1.1","1.2","1.3"};
        String[] arr1 = {"2.1","2.2","2.3"};

        List<String[]> l = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        l.add(arr);
        l.add(arr1);

        List<List<String[]>> data = new ArrayList<List<String[]>> ();
            data.add(l);

        return data;
    }

}

public class Test {

    static <T> List<T> makeList(DTOInt<T> inp){
        T data = inp.getData();
        List<T> list = (List<T>) data;
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(makeList(new DTO()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this works at runtime is because generics do not exist at runtime, they are implemented purely on the compiler side. During compilation, the generics are removed by a process called "type erasure".

All the runtime sees is that your method `DTO.getData()` is returning a result of type `List`. This result is returned from the `makeList()` method, which -- in the runtime's point of view -- returns a `List` as well, so the runtime is happy.

Of course, this only works because `DTO` really returns a `List` result. If you would create a second class

```
class DTO2 implements DTOInt<Integer> { ... }
```

then casting the result of `DTO2.getData()` to `List` will indeed throw an exception.